# Calculating the differential operator

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $S^1$ be the unit sphere, $D^2$ the unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $M = S^1 \times D^2$. Let $f : M \to M$, 
$$f(\varphi, x, y) = (2 \varphi, \frac{1}{10} x + \frac{1}{2} \cos \varphi, \frac{1}{10} y + \frac{1}{2} \sin \varphi).$$
I don't know how to calculate the differential $Df_{(\varphi, x, y)}(u,v_1,v_2)$, where 
$$Df_{(\varphi, x, y)} : T_{(\varphi, x, y)} M \to T_{(\varphi, x, y)} M.$$
Can someone explain me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just compute the Jacobian matrix
\begin{align}
Df=
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 &0\\
-\frac{1}{2}\sin\varphi & \frac{1}{10} & 0\\
\frac{1}{2}\cos\varphi & 0 & \frac{1}{10}
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}